# Populating list from Database - System.InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a simple class that I want to populate a list of from a database:

```
class Foreman
{
    public int ForeBadge { get; set; }
    public string ForeName { get; set; }
}
```

Heres my method that is supposed to return a list of Foreman objects:

```
    static public List<Foreman> getForeman()
    {
        connectionString.DataSource = "server";
        connectionString.InitialCatalog = "db";
        connectionString.UserID = "tunnelld";
        connectionString.Password = "pw";

        string queryString = "SELECT * FROM [QTRAXAdmin].[vwQT_Foreman]";

        List<Foreman> list;
        // Creates a SQL connection
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ToString()))
        {
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    list = new List<Foreman>();
                    while (reader.Read())
                        list.Add(new Foreman { ForeBadge = reader.GetInt32(0), ForeName = reader.GetString(1) });
                }
            }
            connection.Close();
            return list;
        }
```

The method is erroring out at `list.Add(new Foreman { ForeBadge = reader.GetInt32(0), ForeName = reader.GetString(1) });`

with: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Data.dll

To me it looks like I'm using the correct variable types. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what columns vwQT_Foreman has? Looks like first column in result is not int

Comment: @Vitaliy, You are right. For some reason the view is returning the primary key as a varchar....

Comment: what are the data-types of the columns - better use their name instead of an index

Comment: What are the native SQL Server types of the two columns you're selecting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the field names explicitly in your query to ensure columns are coming back in the order you think they are.  That is the most suspicious thing I see.  Alternatively you could use column names in your using block.  And of course double check the column definition in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the table column names are forebadge and forename, replace:

```
string queryString = "SELECT * FROM [QTRAXAdmin].[vwQT_Foreman]";
```

with:

```
string queryString = "SELECT FOREBADGE, FORENAME FROM [QTRAXAdmin].[vwQT_Foreman]";
```